# Shadow like border outside Border element in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need my component to have a border that is dark closer to the component and then it fades out going away. DropShadowEffect appears on two side only (right and lower) while I want it on all four sides.
Here's what I need

[image: here's what I need]

While I currently have something like,

[image: what I have right now]

And here's my current code,

```
<Border x:Name="ShadowBorder" BorderThickness="1" Width="242" Height="280" Margin="5,5,5,5">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" Center="0.5,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="1"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
</Border>
```

Comment: I'd try to use `DropShadowEffect` and play with `BlurRadius` and `Opacity`. Hmm.. perhaps using multiple `DropShadowEffect` with different `Direction` will do? Otherwise you may try to write a custom pixel shader with shadow effects in multiple direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track using DropShadowEffect.  The reason why it only blurred on two sides was because of your `ShadowDepth`.  Set it to 0, and you will get what you want.

```
<Border x:Name="ShadowBorder" BorderThickness="1" Width="242" Height="280" Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="#00FFFFFF">
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Width="242" Height="280"/>
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0" Color="LightBlue"/>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
```

Here's what it will look like:

[image]